# Submitting a form view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, view, controller, http-post

I have a form in my form view defined as

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

This form contins a number of input of type button and button

```
<input type="submit" value="val1" name="action">
<input type="submit" value="val2" name="action">
<input type="submit" value="val3" name="action" />
<button class="button" type="submit" name="action" value="val4">Val4</button>
```

I have 2 controllers for this view

```
Public ActionResult form{
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult form(String button)
{
  switch (actionType)
  {
    case "val1":
      return RedirectToAction("AnotherView"); 
    case "val2":
      return RedirectToAction("AnotherView2");
    default:
      return RedirectToAction("AnotherView3");
  }
}
```

But whichever button I click, I am being redirected to the Home defined in the form

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home",
```

My question is how can I fix this and how can I be certain that this post method is bound to my view as i just typed it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (Html.BeginForm("action_name", "controllername", FormMethod.GET, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

use input type select:

```
<select name="action">
<option value="val1" >val1</option>
<option value="val2" >val2</option>
<option value="val3" >val3</option></select>
```

and method at controller

```
public ActionResult action_name(String action){
   switch (action)
  {
        case "val1":
          return RedirectToAction("AnotherView"); 
        case "val2":
          return RedirectToAction("AnotherView2");
        default:
          return RedirectToAction("AnotherView3");
  }
}
```

Comment: No error. It just goes over to the action_name method of my controller. btw, what do you mean by action_name and controllername in "using (Html.BeginForm("action_name", "controllername"...". Do you mean action_name= method name = form(for my example) and controllername = HomeController (as that is the name of the controller with my form method)?

Comment: The values "action_name" and "controllername" should be replaced by values of the controller and method in that controller you want executed when the form is submit.  So if you had a class named AccountController with method named ProcessForm, it would be: Html.BeginForm("ProcessForm", "Account", .....

Comment: you create form with using (Html.BeginForm("action_name", "controllername... -> that form you crate will be submited to that controller at that action

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a form field named `action` MVC will interpret this as the action on the controller to route to. Thus clicking `val1` will ultimately execute the method:

```
public ActionResult val1()
{
}
```

If this method does not exist, your error handling will take over.

Solution:  *Don't use `action` as a name of a form field.*